# GNU linker: alternative to --version-script to list exported symbols at the command line?

Tags: linux, linker, symbols

On Linux with the GNU toolchain, I know how to control exported symbols from a shared library with a version script (gcc -Wl,--version-script=symbols.map), but I would like to list exported symbols on the command line instead. IOW, I would like the equivalent of

```
link /EXPORT:foo
```

from the MS toolchain. Is it possible ?

EDIT:

My question may not be very clearn: if I have a library libfoo.so, and I want to only export libraries foo1 and foo2, I can go create a version script foo.linux as follows

```
libfoo.so
{
global:
    foo1;
    foo2;
local:
    *;
}
```

And do

```
gcc -shared foo.c -Wl,--version-script=foo.linux -o libfoo.so -soname libfoo.so
```

I would like to be able to do something like this instead:

```
gcc -shared foo.c -Wl,--export-symbol=foo1 -Wl,--export-symbol=foo2 -o libfoo.so -soname libfoo.so
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can do this like you want.
One way is with the linker version script like you mentioned. Another way is to add in your source code `__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))` for whatever you want exported and compile everything with `-fvisibility=hidden`

Comment: Yep, it seems that doing what I want is simply not possible at the moment. Using attribute is exactly what I want to avoid

Answer (score 4):

I may be eight years late, but yes, you actually can do what you want.

Use Bash [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
gcc -shared foo.c -Wl,--version-script=<(echo "{global:foo1;foo2;local:*;};") -o libfoo.so -soname libfoo.so
```

Answer (score -3):

readelf and objdump have lots of options. How about:

```
readelf --symbols --use-dynamic $yourlib.so
```