# How to remove unused references from a shared library (elf/gcc)

Tags: c, gcc, linker, android-ndk, ld

I'm building a shared library that contains a public interface found some object file public.o

The shared library is composed of 100+ other objects files and I want to minimize the size if the .so file. Is there a way to remove of all the symbols from from the shared library that are not referenced by public.o? Alternatively, is there a way to retain only dependencies of extern "C" functions, stripping all of the unused C++ names?

Comment: Question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088409/stripping-linux-shared-libraries

Answer (score 2):

Look at this manual:
http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility 
it explains for example how to handle C++ names stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a recent GCC (e.g. a 4.6.1 version) and pass `-flto` at compile and at (library) link time.

(*added*) You could also play with the [visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) attribute.

But I won't bother about the size of an *.so

Comment: Stripping the unused symbols reduces our library size from 15Mb to 300kb. Its for an embedded Linux device - this is quite a saving.